# any way to declare an immutable linkedhashmap in Java 11

Tags: java, java-11

If I want to declare a map of constants, with java 11 I can do this:

```
 Map<String, String> map = Map.of(
      key, value,
      key, value,
      etc. etc
 )
```

For my purpose, I need a **LinkedHashMap** because I need to keep safe the order in which the key value couples are definied, mainly because I need to stream and find first element in the map.

Something like:

```
   return map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getValue != null))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
```

Any hints?

Comment: Doesn't that actually make it just a list of tuples, and instead of bothering with streams, you'd do something like `list.get(0).getKey()`? What's your actual problem? What are you storing and what kind of access patterns do you have?

Comment: In other words, when all you care for, is an ordered `entrySet().stream()`, you can use `List.of(Map.entry(key1, value1), Map.entry(key2, value2), etc)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put( "key1", "value1" );
map.put( "key2", "value2" );
…
map = Collections.unmodifiableMap( map );
```

You cannot use `Map.of()` as this would not preserve the sequence of entry. In addition, `Map.of()` will not accept `null` values, neither for the key nor for the value. And according to the second code snippet you will expect some keys that are linked to `null`.

Comment: To be fair, original code matched for a blank string, which seems to work fine. I've changed with null check there but I've not thought about this side effect